# Text with two colors

Tags: css, svg

I would like to have a text that switches its color at a certain point x. I have provided a sample that uses the text twice to produce the result, with the switch at 45px. Is there a way to do this in css without having the text twice? Maybe using svg?

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
div>span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div :nth-child(2){
  color: blue;
  clip: rect(0 200px 40px 45px);
}
div :nth-child(1){
  color: red;
  clip: rect(0 45px 40px 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>Some bicolored Text</span>
<span>Some bicolored Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to have color of some text with different color in the beginning then you can look for `:before`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not just using `<span class="red">red text</span><span class="blue"> blue text</span>`? As that would be way easier

Comment: @Marv yes, look closely, half of the "b" in the sample is of one color, the other half differently colored.

Comment: Ah alright, looking at the browser at my small screen, nevermind then!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possible option is to use SVG. You can create multi colored text in SVG using gradients. If two adjacent gradient stops are at the same position then you will get a sharp transition between colors. If two adjacent gradient stops are at different positions then you will get a smooth transition between colors. You can have as many color stops as you want. For example...

```
<svg width="200" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="bicolored">
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="blue"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="tricolored">
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="green"/>
            <stop offset="66%" stop-color="green"/>
            <stop offset="66%" stop-color="blue"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="smooth">
            <stop offset="33%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="66%" stop-color="blue"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text x="0" y="20" fill="url(#bicolored)">Some bicolored Text</text>
    <text x="0" y="40" fill="url(#tricolored)">Some tricolored Text</text>
    <text x="0" y="60" fill="url(#smooth)">Some smooth gradient Text</text>
</svg>
```

Note that in SVG, the color stops are at relative positions (e.g. 0 to 1, 0% to 100%). This could make it a little hard if you are trying to place the color stops at specific pixel locations.

Note that in SVG, you have to manually position the text element within the svg element.

Comment: the cleanest solution so far - looks like I had the right idea when I suggested svg

Answer (score 14):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content:attr(data-text);
}

div:after{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div:after {
  color: blue;
  clip: rect(0 200px 40px 45px);
}

div:before {
  color: red;
  clip: rect(0 45px 40px 0);
}
```

```html
<div data-text="Some bicolored Text">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the text is not selectable anymore, but I still like the solution, combined with @web-tiki. Unfortunately that will produce double text on copy again, *sigh*.

Comment: `will produce double text on copy` What do you mean? I tried to copy the text in @web-tiki answer and it copy this just once.

Comment: in IE, I got `BicolorBicolor` when I selected and copied it.

Comment: @manuFS IE handles selection differently. One of the *very few* things that IE hasn't fixed. Unfortunately IE got a bad name, so they renamed it to Edge, and Edge 13... Just try it on Edge.

Answer (score 12):

In Webkit only we have the `-webkit-background-clip:text` property/value.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 36px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red 50%, blue 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>LONG HEADING TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: You save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a pseudo element for this. It will allow you to

- change the color in the middle of a letter
- keep the semantics of the content displayed
- prevent semantic duplicate content

```css
h1{
  position:relative;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#000;
}
h1:before{
  content: attr(data-content);
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:2.2em;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="Bicolor">Bicolor<h1>
```

output :

[image: text with 2 colors]

*Note that the `clip` property [has been deprecated](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#clip-property). In this example, I used the overflow property instead for the same result.*

Comment: Until ua's support clip-path, I guess they won't kill clip. However of course the overflow does the job, too. The blue text in the background behind the red text does produce some visual artifacts though. Guess you could fix that with left: x px and margin-left: -x px

Comment: @manuFS you can also add a background-color to the pseudo element to remove the artifact like this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/j942uhes/

Answer (score 5):

Got it! Mixed a few things from the answers together to get this:

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div>span{
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 3;
}

div:before, div:after{
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
div:before{
  color: blue;
  clip: rect(0 200px 40px 45px);
  z-index: 1;
}
div:after{
  color: red;
  clip: rect(0 45px 40px 0);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div data-content="Some bicolored Text">
    <span>Some bicolored Text</span>
</div>
```

Upvoted all the answers for partial solutions.

Comment: As commented before, clip has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want absolute sizing, you can do this in SVG using a filter.

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="800px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 800 50">
  <defs>
    <filter id="bicolor">
      <feFlood x="0" y="0" width="800" height="50" flood-color="blue" result="blue-field"/>
      <feFlood x="50" y="0" width="750" height="50" flood-color="red" result="red-field"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="blue-field"/>
        <feMergeNode in="red-field"/>
        </feMerge>
        <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>
      <text filter="url(#bicolor)" x="20" y="20" width="200" height="20">BICOLOR Text and stuff</text>
  </svg>
```